# Strongly component

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search, strongly-connected-graph

I am trying to write an algorithm that is given a graph G and 2 nodes 'x' and 'y'as input, which returns whether there is a cyclic path from 'x' to 'y'

Is it a good idea to find the strongly connected components first and then check if x and y belong to same strongly connected component.
 If they belong to different connected component say x belongs to C1 and y belongs to C2, then if there exists a path from C1 to C2, then we can say that there is a cyclic path from x to y.

Comment: When you say "a cyclic path from 'x' to 'y'", do you mean that x and y are on the same cycle, or there is a path from 'x' to 'y' that contains a cycle?

Comment: A path from 'x' to 'y' that contains a cycle..

Comment: How do you define a cycle? In principle, you could go back and forth on an edge to form the cycle.

Comment: @NicoSchertler The word "graph" can mean a directed or an undirected graph.  As soon as someone throws around phrases like "strongly connected", they are usually talking about a directed graph.

Comment: Are you looking for any solution, or feedback on the particular solution you propose?

Comment: Feedback, like where will it fail?

Comment: Well, you problem seems to be an exact statement of strong connectivity: two vertices are strongly connected if and only if there exists a directed cycle that contains them both. So Kosaraju-Sharir for SCC will solve the task. You can of course check if digraph is acyclic before building SCC in which case the answer will be no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea with strongly connected components should work. Here is a graph and some code for you to experiment:

First, a digraph:

[image]

And it's adjacency lists representation:

```
13 vertices, 22 edges
0: 5 1
1: 
2: 0 3
3: 5 2
4: 3 2
5: 4
6: 9 4 8 0
7: 6 9
8: 6
9: 11 10
10: 12
11: 4 12
12: 9
```

And it's strongly connected components:

[image]

```
7
6 8
9 10 11 12
0 2 3 4 5
1
```

Now, after with implementation for digraph and Kosaraju-Sharir

```
class StronglyConnectedComponents
{
    private bool[] visited;
    private int[] componentIds;
    public int ComponentCount { get; private set; }

    public StronglyConnectedComponents(DirectedGraph graph)
    {
        visited = new bool[graph.VertexCount];
        componentIds = new int[graph.VertexCount];

        var order = new GraphTraversal(graph).ReverseOrder();
        var reversedGraph = graph.Reverse();
        foreach (var vertex in order)
        {
            if (!visited[vertex])
            {
                DepthFirstSearch(reversedGraph, vertex);
                ComponentCount++;
            }
        }
    }

    public int VertexComponentId(int vertex)
    {
        return componentIds[vertex];
    }

    public bool AreStronglyConnected(int source, int target)
    {
        return componentIds[source] == componentIds[target];
    }

    private void DepthFirstSearch(DirectedGraph graph, int vertex)
    {
        visited[vertex] = true;
        componentIds[vertex] = ComponentCount;
        foreach (var adjacent in graph.AdjacentTo(vertex))
        {
            if (!visited[adjacent])
            {
                DepthFirstSearch(graph, adjacent);
            }
        }
    }
}

class GraphTraversal
{
    private Stack<int> reversePostOrder;
    private bool[] visited;

    public GraphTraversal(DirectedGraph graph)
    {
        visited = new bool[graph.VertexCount];
        reversePostOrder = new Stack<int>();

        for (var vertex = 0; vertex < graph.VertexCount; vertex++)
        {
            if (!visited[vertex])
            {
                DepthFirstSearch(graph, vertex);
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<int> ReverseOrder()
    {
        return reversePostOrder;
    }

    private void DepthFirstSearch(DirectedGraph graph, int vertex)
    {
        visited[vertex] = true;
        foreach (var adjacent in graph.AdjacentTo(vertex))
        {
            if (!visited[adjacent])
            {
                DepthFirstSearch(graph, adjacent);
            }
        }
        reversePostOrder.Push(vertex);
    }
}

class DirectedGraph
{
    public int VertexCount { get; set; }
    public int EdgeCount { get; set; } = 0;

    private List<int>[] adjacencyLists;

    public DirectedGraph(int vertexCount)
    {
        VertexCount = vertexCount;
        InitializeAdjacencyLists(vertexCount);
    }

    public void AddEdge(int from, int to)
    {
        adjacencyLists[from].Add(to);
        EdgeCount++;
    }

    public IEnumerable<int> AdjacentTo(int vertex)
    {
        return adjacencyLists[vertex];
    }

    public DirectedGraph Reverse()
    {
        var reversedGraph = new DirectedGraph(this.VertexCount);
        for (var vertex = 0; vertex < this.VertexCount; vertex++)
        {
            foreach (var adjacent in this.AdjacentTo(vertex))
            {
                reversedGraph.AddEdge(adjacent, vertex);
            }
        }
        return reversedGraph;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        String graghString = VertexCount + " vertices, " + EdgeCount + " edges \n";
        for (int vertex = 0; vertex < VertexCount; vertex++)
        {
            graghString += vertex + ": ";
            foreach (var adjacnet in this.AdjacentTo(vertex))
            {
                graghString += adjacnet + " ";
            }
            graghString += "\n";
        }
        return graghString;
    }

    private void InitializeAdjacencyLists(int vertexCount)
    {
        adjacencyLists = new List<int>[vertexCount];
        for (var vertex = 0; vertex < vertexCount; vertex++)
        {
            adjacencyLists[vertex] = new List<int>();
        }
    }
}
```

Queries like `scc.AreStronglyConnected(2, 5)` will tell if directed cycle between vertices exists. Runnable code is [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BaHfI2).

Comment: I think line graphs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph) class of undirected graph. Connectivity for undirected graphs plays by sort of different rule - you can find connected components with simple DFS. Or you can use Union Find datastructure instead. So this really depends if your graph is directed or undirected. You can also construct the graph you are interested, put in the code in the link i provided and see if result matches your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

*I am assuming you want to count paths having 'x' or 'y' multiple times as well.*

If 'x' and 'y' belong to same strongly connected component, there exists a path containing a cycle. (trivial, by definition of strongly connected component)

However, if they belong to different strongly connected components, 'y' should be reachable from 'x' and **at least one component having a node on the path must have size more than one**. (Take any cycle in that component and continue on the path)

Your solution will fail in case of a linear graph. There is no cycle, yet you can reach from 'x' to 'y' which belong to different strongly connected components.